# Django IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed

Tags: python, django, django-models, unique-constraint

I'm trying to prevent a certain Insert if a `product` has `base_image=True` but allow as many insertions as we want when `base_image=False`.

I've implemented it with `django.db.models.UniqueConstraint`, **EVERYTHING WORKS FINE** but in django admin panel instead of getting a red alert in adding view, I'm getting `IntegrityError`.

here is my model (`media.py`):

```py
from django.db import models
from apiv1.models.products import Product

class Media(models.Model):
    """ Media table, contains images file names """

    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='media', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=191, blank=False, unique=True)
    base_image = models.BooleanField(blank=False)

    class Meta:

        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=[
                    'product',
                ],
                condition=models.Q(base_image=True),
                name='unique_base_image'
            ),
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.file_name
```

and this is the error:

```
IntegrityError at /admin/apiv1/media/add/

UNIQUE constraint failed: apiv1_media.product_id

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/apiv1/media/add/
Django Version:     3.1.4
Exception Type:     IntegrityError
Exception Value:    

UNIQUE constraint failed: apiv1_media.product_id

Exception Location:     /Users/sal/devel/artiashco_tipnety_cbir/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py, line 413, in execute
Python Executable:  /Users/sal/devel/artiashco_tipnety_cbir/env/bin/python
Python Version:     3.7.3
Python Path:    

['/Users/sal/devel/artiashco_tipnety_cbir',
 '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip',
 '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7',
 '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/sal/devel/artiashco_tipnety_cbir/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages']

Server time:    Wed, 30 Dec 2020 12:58:16 +0000
```

**Expectation:** red bootstrap alert in django admin panel

Comment: What database are you using as conditional clauses are ignored on some such as MySQL and MariaDB - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/indexes/#django.db.models.Index.condition

Comment: thanks for the point, it's sqlite, have to search more about your point